# How can I style previous element with a:hover?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class = "label">
     Label
  </div>
  <a class = "content" href= "........">
     // a lot of different divs in here
  </a>
</div>
```

I want to add a:visited state to this link that also styles the sibling  of class `label`. I have found out how to style the children divs of  but not sure how to style the previous sibling. I want to accomplish this with only CSS.

Current CSS: (gray out all child divs of `<a>` when visited)

```
content:hover .childdiv1 .childdiv2 .childdiv3 {
   color: gray;
}
```

Comment: `.outer` is the parent, not a sibling, and CSS cannot traverse up the tree.

Comment: Made a typo and meant class `label`, edited the post for clarity.

Comment: There's also no previous sibling selector. That's still "up the tree". CSS doesn't look back during rendering.

Comment: Unfortunately, css doesnt change parent style based on child status, and with siblings you can only change those that come after, not before (in your case, `label` can change `content` but `content` cant change `label`.

Comment: If you are able to reorder the elements, this is achievable using `+` (You can style the `.label` to appear first visually, the `a` just needs to be first in the DOM)